# Submit form and fetch data from website VBA

Tags: excel, vba, msxml, mshtml

I'm trying to fetch data from this [site](http://www.finanztreff.de/) using VBA in Excel. What I tried to do and what worked was using InternetExplorer object like this:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = False
IE.Navigate "http://zertifikate.finanztreff.de"
IE.document.getElementById("USFsecuritySearchDropDown").Value = "DE000BP5TBQ2"
IE.document.getElementById("USFsecuritySearchDropDownForm").submit

Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4  'wait until page is loaded
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop
MsgBox IE.document.getElementById("BP5TBQ~30~5").innerHTML
```

However this worked very slow and didn't get always the right results. I suspect that sometimes it didn't wait until webpage was loaded. I tried to look for answers and I found [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480369/vba-hanging-on-ie-busy-and-readystate-check). Now I'm trying to figure out how to rewrite my macro using MSXML2 and MSHTML. So far I was able to do this :

```
Dim IE As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Set IE = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

IE.Open "GET", "http://zertifikate.finanztreff.de", False
IE.send
While IE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Wend

Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim htmlBody As MSHTML.htmlBody

Set HTMLDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set htmlBody = HTMLDoc.body
htmlBody.innerHTML = IE.responseText
HTMLDoc.getElementById("USFsecuritySearchDropDown").Value = "DE000BP5TBQ2"
```

please, why HTMLDoc has method getElementById and htmlBody doesn't ? How could I submit form "USFsecuritySearchDropDownForm". I tried this :

```
 HTMLDoc.getElementById("USFsecuritySearchDropDownForm").submit
```

, but it always open new window in my default browser, I would like to have it hidden.
It seems to me that I am missing difference between XMLHTTP60 and MSHTML.HTMLDocument.
If you could please help me or at least show me where I can find this information I would be really thankful...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

XMLHTTP sends an http request to the webserver and receives back a response. MSHTML receives a string and renders the HTML. When you use them together, XMLHTTP gets the webserver response and MSHTML puts that response in a form you can use.

I think you don't need to submit anything. If you go to the site and type in the ticker, you get to a page like

http://zertifikate.finanztreff.de/dvt_einzelkurs_uebersicht.htn?seite=zertifikate&i=22558284&suchbegriff=DE000BP5TBQ2&exitPoint=

That has the ticker in it. You can "GET" that URL directly and get whatever information you need from the html that's returned. This example gets what I assume is the stock price.

```
Sub GetPrice()

    Dim xHttp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Dim hDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim hDiv As HTMLDivElement
    Dim hTbl As HTMLTable

    Const sTICKER As String = "DE000BP5TBQ2"

    Set xHttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP

    xHttp.Open "GET", "http://zertifikate.finanztreff.de/dvt_einzelkurs_uebersicht.htn?seite=zertifikate&i=22558284&suchbegriff=" & sTICKER & "&exitPoint="
    xHttp.send

    Do Until xHttp.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    If xHttp.Status = 200 Then
        Set hDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        hDoc.body.innerHTML = xHttp.responseText

        'Get the third TD in the first TABLE in the first DIV whose class is 'tape'
        Set hDiv = hDoc.getElementsByClassName("tape").Item(0)
        Set hTbl = hDiv.getElementsByTagName("table").Item(0)
        Debug.Print hTbl.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(2).innerText
    End If

End Sub
```

**Post Example**

```
Sub GetPriceByPost()

    Dim xHttp As MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Dim hDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim hDiv As HTMLDivElement
    Dim hTbl As HTMLTable

    Const sTICKER As String = "i=635957"

    Set xHttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP

    xHttp.Open "POST", "http://fonds.finanztreff.de/fonds_einzelkurs_uebersicht.htn"
    xHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    xHttp.send sTICKER

    Do Until xHttp.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    If xHttp.Status = 200 Then
        Set hDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        hDoc.body.innerHTML = xHttp.responseText

        'Get the third TD in the first TABLE in the first DIV whose class is 'tape'
        Set hDiv = hDoc.getElementsByClassName("tape").Item(0)
        Set hTbl = hDiv.getElementsByTagName("table").Item(0)
       Debug.Print hTbl.getElementsByTagName("td").Item(2).innerText
    Else
        Debug.Print xHttp.statusText
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining the XMLHTTP and MSHTML to me. First I thought also that I can use GET, however if I change sTICKER="DE000BP72DA4" it shows me the previous price instead, i think also the ?i= parameter matters. Could I also ask you to edit your answer and show me also how to submit form with POST? Your answer was very helpful, Thanks

Comment: If I type DE000BP72DA4 in the website, I get the same price. I don't speak German so it's hard to tell what the difference might be. I don't know how to use post with that particular example, but I added another example. I'm not sure why POST didn't work with http://zertifikate.finanztreff.de/dvt_einzelkurs_uebersicht.htn, but did with "fonds..."