# Scraping Macro Freezing after Just a Couple Loops

Tags: excel, vba, loops, macros, screen-scraping

I have a scraping macro that used to work just fine, and is now freezing after just a couple loops (sometimes one). I've done what I can think of to optimize the macro to not take up too much CPU. I am completely confused as to why the macro would be freezing like this. My code is below, any tips or critiques would be much appreciated!

```
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim Rows As Long, IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rngLinks As Range, rngLink As Range

    Sheet1.Cells.ClearContents
    Sheets("Landing Page").Select
    Range("E7").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Sheets("Landing Page").Select
    Range("B5").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy

    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer

    Rows = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngLinks = ws1.Range("A2:A" & Rows)
    i = 2

    With IE
        .Visible = True

        For Each rngLink In rngLinks
            .navigate (rngLink)

            While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
            Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:004"))

            Dim doc As Object, dd As String
            Set doc = IE.document

            On Error GoTo Errorhandler:
            dd = doc.getElementsByClassName("price-display csTile-price")(0).innerText

            ws1.Range("B" & i).Value = dd

            i = i + 1

            Application.StatusBar = i

            dd = ""

            Set IE = Nothing
        Next rngLink
    End With

Errorhandler:

    dd = ""

    Resume Next

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    ws1.Activate
    Set rngLinks = Nothing

    'Strip out everything but total price

    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[-1],FIND("" "",RC[-1])-0)"
    Range("C2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C" & Rows), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("C2:C" & Rows).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                           :=False, Transpose:=False

    'Apply OnlyNums formula to remove delimeters
    Range("D2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=OnlyNums(RC[-1])"
    Range("D2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D" & Rows), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("D2:D" & Rows).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                           :=False, Transpose:=False

    'Add decimal back in
    Range("E2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=iferror(RC[-1]/100,"" "")"
    Range("E2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E" & Rows), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("E2:E" & Rows).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                           :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Style = "Currency"

    'Remove columns C and D
    Columns("C:D").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

    'Add column headers to F and G
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "HTML Export (Raw)"

    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Price"

    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Collection Date"
    Rows2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("D2:D" & Rows2).Value = Date
    Range("E1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Company Store Number"
    Range("F1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "UPC"

    Sheets("Landing Page").Select
    Range("B8").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Sheets("Landing Page").Select
    Range("E8").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Sheets("Landing Page").Select
    Range("D8").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    ws1.Activate

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    Dim acc As New Access.Application

    acc.OpenCurrentDatabase "S:\Aditem\Pricing\Scraping\Database.accdb"
    acc.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
        TransferType:=acImport, _
        SpreadSheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
        TableName:="Company", _
        Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName, _
        HasFieldNames:=True, _
        Range:="Sheet1$C1:F" & Rows
```

Comment: I'm surprised this works at all - remove the `Set IE = Nothing` from inside the `With IE` block.

Comment: You're the best! That was actually leftover from a suggestion by someone else. I removed it, and the macro is cycling fine so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 issues.  First (and likely not related to the issue since you don't mention a run-time error) is that you are releasing the IE object inside your `With IE` block.  Remove this line:

```
Set IE = Nothing
```

The second issue (and more likely the cause of the hang), is that you never test the value of `rngLink` before passing it to `.Navigate`.  If `rngLink` evaluates to `vbNullString`, the IE object will never change the `.readyState` from `READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED`, so your wait loop will never exit. I'd add a simple test:

```
If rngLink <> vbNullString Then
    .navigate rngLink
```

Comment: Hmm, I see where you're coming from with the Set IE = Nothing, but I'm not sure I follow with the second issue. The macro makes it through the .ready state, I think because it's able to cycle through the list of URLs I provide it.

Comment: @HenryK - If you try to pass a `vbNullString` for IE to navigate to, it doesn't do anything. That means this loop: `While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend` will never exit because `.Busy` will be false and `.readyState` will be stuck at 0.

Comment: So I added the step you recommended for the vbnull string and, the macro is freezing again. It makes it through about 20 links, and then just freezes.

Comment: @HenryK - The next step would be to add a timeout to your loop.  [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22113734/4088852).

Comment: You the man again. Running smooth now. Through 100 loops and counting.